# For x < 5 what is the greatest value of x

Tags: paradoxes

It can't be $5$. And it can't be $4.\overline{9}$ because that equals $5$. It looks like there is no solution... but surely there must be?

Comment: Why must there be one?

Comment: I don't know, must there be at least a way to describe it?

Comment: Tom, you already answered your question. There is no nextdoor neighbor to 5. (That counts for both sides of 5)

Comment: @Tom Not all subsets of the real numbers have a maximum, the set $\{x\in \Bbb R: x<5\}$ is one such instance.

Comment: Who says $x$ is a real number. I say $x$ is a number which is less than or equal to $4$ hence the greatest such $x$ is 4. Problem solved ;)

Comment: This is one of those places where we confront the nature of infinite sets:  there is always "room" between a chosen value of $x$ less than 5 and 5 itself to insert yet another number -- 4.9999, 4.99999, 4.999999, etc.

Comment: If $x<5$ then $x<\frac{x+5}{2}<5$. So there is no greatest such $x$.

Comment: What do you mean "must there still be a way to describe it?" There are lots of ways to describe things that don't exist. I can describe a moon made of green cheese, but that doesn't mean it exists.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a clever way of writing it down with limits or something, so that it doesn't describe (or evaluate to) an actual number. But it does not seem so.

Comment: You might be interested in Vihart's video, where she briefly discusses surreal numbers and infinitesimals (an alternate number system where numbers actually CAN be infinitely close to $5$ yet larger than any real number $x < 5$): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TINfzxSnnIE&t=5m2s

Comment: @Adriano Surreal numbers look interesting. So if $x$ is surreal then we can get closer to 5 than all reals with $\epsilon$ = { 4, 4.5, 4.75, … | 5 }. But we still have the same problem. { $\epsilon$ | 5 }, and so on...

Comment: Somehow [the Berry paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox) comes to mind...

Comment: 4 may be the only [interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) solution to this problem.

Comment: @Adriano while the surreal numbers are interesting, they still do not contain a largest element strictly smaller than $5$ (no ordered field will be able to do so).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There isn't one.  Suppose there were; let's call it $y$, where $y<5$.

Let $\epsilon = 5 -y$, the difference between $y$ and 5.  $\epsilon$ is positive, and so $0 < \frac\epsilon2 < \epsilon$, and then $y < y+\frac\epsilon2 < y+\epsilon = 5$, which shows that $y+\frac\epsilon2$ is even closer to 5 than $y$ was.

So there is no number that is closest to 5. Whatever $y$ you pick, however close it is, there is another number that is even closer.

Consider the analogous question: “$x < \infty$; what is the greatest value of $x$?”  There is no such $x$.

Comment: To answer your analogous question, there is no such $x$ as a value, but $x = \infty-\frac1\infty$ would approach the limit quite nicely.

Comment: I brought that up only to illustrate the point that one can make up a set of properties that are not satisfied by any object.

Comment: Actually, if you wanted a simple way to describe this number, couldn't you just say $x = 5 - \frac1\infty$ ?

Comment: You can *say* whatever you like, but hardly anyone will understand what you mean. If you want a simple way to describe this particular collection of properties, then Tom's original description, the greatest $x$ that is less than 5, is perfectly clear.  Your suggestion just obfuscates that.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver What about $\infty - \frac1{2\infty}$? If that doesn't work, so many things are broken.

Answer (score 19):

The answer is $4$, assuming the domain of $x$ is $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The original question mentioned 4.99999, so the intention should have been clear.

Comment: He said $4.999...$ which is in fact an integer.

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: \*facepalm\* +1 :P

Comment: +1 because I always approve of picking an interpretation of a problem that renders it trivial.

Comment: The answer is 3, assuming the domain of x is {3}.

Comment: There are actually many answers depending on domain. 2 (primes), 1 (factors of 5), 0 (multiplies of 5), and $\pi$ ($\{\pi, 5\}$).

Comment: @Plutor. When there is a domain like $\{3\}$, nothing is greater nor anything is smaller.

Answer (score 11):

If $x<5$ then $2x<x+5$ so $x<\frac{x+5}{2}$. Similarly, $x<5$ means $x+5<5+5=10$ or $\frac{x+5}{2}<5$.  So if $x<5$ we have $x<\frac{x+5}{2}<5$, and therefore there is a larger number, $\frac{x+5}{2}$ less than  $5$.

Basically, the average of two different numbers must be strictly between those two numbers.