# why a^2 + b^2 = c^2 in right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

> a^2 + b^2 = c^2

what is the demonstration of this rule with triangle which has 90 deg?
can be proofed using geometry?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675522/whats-the-intuition-behind-pythagoras-theorem and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-is-the-most-elegant-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which notions of geometry can you recall for the demonstration?

[Here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/index.shtml) you can find some different proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: It is not for Phythagore. It is for a Muslim man who is GHeyth Edin ELKASHI : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Kashi